# Simplify z3 bitvector expression, but avoid extract & concat

Tags: python, z3, xor, smt, bitvector

I was wondering whether it's possible to get z3 not to use `Extract` and `Concat` in the output expression when one applies `simplify` on an expression with bitvectors.

For example, instead of

```py
>>> x = BitVector("x", 32)
>>> simplify(x ^ 7 ^ 6)
Concat(Extract(31, 1, x), ~Extract(0, 0, x))
```

I'd like to have

```py
>>> x = BitVector("x", 32)
>>> simplify(x ^ 7 ^ 6)
x ^ 1
```

I had a look at `help_simplify`, but I couldn't find such an "option".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not easily. `z3` converts `XOR` with numerals to a mask fairly early in the rewriter, and there appears to be no easy way to control that behavior. See here: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/ast/rewriter/bv_rewriter.cpp#L1817-L1823

Having said that, the advantage of the programmable API is that z3 gives you all the tools to code such transformations yourself. This does *not* mean it is easy to do so, but at least it exposes all the necessary bits and pieces. While doing a complete job of doing exactly the rewrites you want can be a large task, you can get away with something simple like this:

```py
def constFold(e):
    try:
       if is_app(e) and all([is_bv_value(c) for c in e.children()]):
          return simplify(e)
       else:
          return e
    except:
        return e
```

This is extremely simple-minded; and it actually doesn't even handle the problem you posed:

```
>>> constFold(x^6^7)
x ^ 6 ^ 7
```

But it does handle this:

```
>>> constFold(x^(6^7))
x ^ 1
```

But for 8 lines of code, it's not too bad! The point is that you can improve upon it as you walk down the structure of expressions, recognize associativity/commutativity etc., and do whatever transformations you want on the AST as exposed by the programmable API.

Keep in mind that if you're using this in a solver context you have to maintain a bunch of invariants and if you do an "incorrect" transformation, you can easily render the solver unsound. With great power, comes great responsibility! Nonetheless, a lot can be achieved with relatively simple programming, if you're willing to study the API and do a deep dive.

Good luck!